# What can I return in my transaction when no writes are made?

Tags: angular, firebase, promise, transactions

I'm working with a database transaction in my angular/firebase project. It looks like this:

```
const transactionResult = await db.runTransaction(async trans => {
        // Get references:
        const parentGroupRef = db.collection('Groups').doc(parentGroupID);
        const childGroupRef = db.collection('Groups').doc(childGroupID);

        // Get documents:
        const promiseArray: Promise<any>[] = [];
        promiseArray.push(trans.get(parentGroupRef));
        promiseArray.push(trans.get(childGroupRef));
        const promiseResults: any[] = await Promise.all(promiseArray);

        // Get the group documents of the promise results:
        const parentGroupDoc = promiseResults.filter(groupDoc => { return groupDoc.id === parentGroupID; })[0];
        const childGroupDoc = promiseResults.filter(groupDoc => { return groupDoc.id === childGroupID; })[0];

        // Get data:
        if (parentGroupDoc && parentGroupDoc.exists && childGroupDoc && childGroupDoc.exists) {
            const parentGroupData = parentGroupDoc.data();
            const childGroupData = childGroupDoc.data();

            // Add child to parent and visa-versa:
            const results: any[] = [];
            if (parentGroupData.childGroupIDs.indexOf(childGroupID) === -1) {
                parentGroupData.childGroupIDs.push(childGroupID);   
                const addChildResult = trans.set(parentGroupRef, parentGroupData, {merge: true});
                results.push(addChildResult);
            }

            if (childGroupData.parentGroupIDs.indexOf(parentGroupID) === -1) {
                childGroupData.parentGroupIDs.push(parentGroupID);
                const addParentResult = trans.set(childGroupRef, childGroupData, {merge: true});
                results.push(addParentResult);
            }

            if (results.length > 0) {
                return await Promise.all(results);
            } else {
                return Promise.reject('No changes made’); // <—- This line here
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Could not find parent or child group, or both.');
            return Promise.reject('Could not find parent or child group, or both.’);
        }
    });
```

It essentially grabs two groups from the database—a parent group and a child group—then it attempts to add the child group to the parent group and visa-versa.

Before it does so, however, it checks to see if the parent group is already a part of the child group. If so, it skips the adding of the parent group to the child group. And similarly for add the child group to the parent group.

If both parent and child groups are already a part of each other, it doesn’t add either. This is the condition I want to handle. I’m currently handling it by returning a rejected promise (the part where I commented “This line here”). But I don’t want it to error in this case. If both groups are already a part of each other, I’d like it to simply return quietly. Therefore, I’d prefer to return a resolved promise. But this doesn’t work. If I return a resolved promise, the transaction throws an error to the effect of:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of null
```

I’m guessing if I resolve it to a transaction object (like what trans.set(…) returns), it will be happy. But how can I return a transaction object when I’m not doing any writes? Is there a null or default transaction I can create? Is there some other object I can return?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you just return null?

Comment: Where do you attempt to read the property `seconds`? It doesn't appear in the code you posted.

Comment: I assume it's something on the transaction that it expects to be returned. Not part of my code.

Comment: Does the stack trace tell you anything?